# PowerShell New-SPWeb doesn't fire Event Receiver

Tags: powershell, site-definition

I have a custom Site Definition that includes a feature that has an Event Receiver.  When creating the custom site via the UI, the Event Receiver fires just fine.  But when I create the same site via:

```
 New-SPWeb -Url http://SPServer/NewWeb -Template "CUSTOMSITEDEF#0" -Name "New Site"
```

the Event Receiver doesn't fire.  I saw another post and I made sure to run it in the SharePoint Management PowerShell.  I'm adding the feature to the Site Definition by adding to the Configuration section of my onet.xml:

```
<Configuration ID="0" Name="CustomSiteDef" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master">
      <Lists />
      <Modules>
        <Module Name="CustomModule" />
      </Modules>
      <SiteFeatures>
        <!-- BasicWebParts Feature -->
        <Feature ID="00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57" />
        <!-- Three-state Workflow Feature -->
        <Feature ID="FDE5D850-671E-4143-950A-87B473922DC7" />
      </SiteFeatures>
      <WebFeatures>
        <!-- TeamCollab Feature -->
        <Feature ID="00BFEA71-4EA5-48D4-A4AD-7EA5C011ABE5" />
        <!-- MobilityRedirect -->
        <Feature ID="F41CC668-37E5-4743-B4A8-74D1DB3FD8A4" />
        <!-- Cusotm Feature -->
        <Feature ID="c3a62d2c-7244-406e-a279-e1fdba43994d" />
      </WebFeatures>
    </Configuration>
```

and the EventReceiver fires off of the ItemAdded event (when the page is created).  Has anyone seen any similar issues?  Should the PowerShell New-SPWeb act identically to creating a Site via the UI?

Below is my webtemp_custom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Templates xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
  <Template Name="CustomSiteDefinitions" ID="10002">
    <Configuration ID="0" Title="Custom Team Site" Hidden="FALSE"
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stts.png" Description=""
        DisplayCategory=" Sites" AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations="TRUE" >
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="1" Title="Custom Blank Site" Hidden="FALSE"
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stbs.png" Description=""
        DisplayCategory=" Sites" AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations="TRUE" >
    </Configuration>
  </Template>
</Templates>
```

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I got exactly this working on another setup.

What permissions are you running your cmd-let with?

Make sure he has the privileges to execute the code in question (eg. full control of web application).

Also post your webtemp xml. I have seen discrepancies before, but that was when provisioning providers from webtemp xml was involved.

Comment: I thought you were onto something when I saw that my AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations was set to False.  But I changed it to true, reset IIS and am still seeing issues.  I'm running the script as administrator in the PowerShell Management console, and it's creating the sites just fine.

Comment: And below is my webtemp_custom.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Templates xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
  <Template Name="CustomSiteDefinitions" ID="10002">
    <Configuration ID="0" Title="Custom Team Site" Hidden="FALSE"
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stts.png" Description=""
        DisplayCategory=" Sites" AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations="TRUE" >
    </Configuration>  
  </Template>
</Templates>

Comment: but are the account used for the shell owner of the site? Try using the same account you use from browser. Also please post code from event handler

Comment: FYI I figured out what the issue was here.  Turns out any changes I was making weren't getting picked up unless I closed my PowerShell window and re-opened it.  I knew PowerShell was loading the SharePoint assemblies from the snap-in, now I'm gonna look into what else is going on here...

Comment: oh yeah, i tried that many times as well. Dont know why i didnt think of that one X-). Found no workaround for that one, but its a good prac. to close those shells when you have done any kind of provisioning for exactly that reason